# BeautifulSoup error handling for findAll()

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping data from this [link](https://www.malaysiastock.biz/Corporate-Infomation.aspx?securityCode=5090). Is there any way I can make error handling for the findAll() in the code below?

Right now the table has nothing :

[image]

My code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36 '
}

def testingCode(stockIdNumber):
    MalaysiaStockBizURL = requests.get(str('https://www.malaysiastock.biz/Corporate-Infomation.aspx?securityCode='+ str(stockIdNumber)),headers=header)
    MalaysiaStockBizParser = BeautifulSoup(MalaysiaStockBizURL.text, 'html.parser')
    
    try:
        shareholdingChangesTable = MalaysiaStockBizParser.find('table', { 'id': 'ctl19_gvShareholdingChange'}).findAll('tr', limit=11)
        for testShare in shareholdingChangesTable:
            titleelem = testShare.find('td')
            if titleelem:
                print(titleelem)
                
            else:
                print("Error")
    
    except IndexError:
        print("Malaysia Stockbiz - Error on Shareholding Changes.")
    
testingCode('5090') # This one has error ''NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'', so need error handling
#testingCode('0105') # This one return some result
```

I can make error handling if the code is `MalaysiaStockBizParser.find('table', { 'id': 'ctl19_gvShareholdingChange'})` as it will produce `None`. But I cannot if using `MalaysiaStockBizParser.find('table', { 'id': 'ctl19_gvShareholdingChange'}).findAll('tr', limit=11)`. This will bring me directly into error '`NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll`'. Any idea on how can I make them possible?

You can refer to this [link](https://www.malaysiastock.biz/Corporate-Infomation.aspx?securityCode=0105) as example how the table should display:
[image]

Comment: What table you want to find? There are no such table with id `ctl19_gvShareholdingChange`

Comment: Check my below answer, Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to catch wrong error. As it is seen in the error message you are getting AttributeError, so you need to catch that one. Changing except statement to this will solve the issue:

```
try:
    # do something
except AttributeError:
    # do another thing
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for this! Yeah, I get my error handling now!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {
 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'
}

stock_id_number = '0105'

biz_url = requests.get(
    'https://www.malaysiastock.biz/Corporate-Infomation.aspx?securityCode={}'.format(
        stock_id_number
    ), headers=header
)
biz_soup = BeautifulSoup(biz_url.text, 'html.parser')

soup_table = biz_soup.find('table', {'id': 'ctl19_gvShareholdingChange'})
rows = soup_table.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    for col in cols:
        print(col.text)
    print('====')
```

```
====
23 Jun 2021
Acquired 200,000
MR LIM TECK SENG
====
22 Jun 2021
Acquired 200,000
MR LIM TECK SENG
====
23 Apr 2021
Disposed 750,000
MR LIM TECK SENG
====
19 Apr 2021
Acquired 2,040,000
DATO' YEO BOON LEONG
====
19 Apr 2021
Acquired 2,040,000
DATO' YEO BOON LEONG
====
16 Apr 2021
Acquired 1,080,000
DATO' YEO BOON LEONG
====
16 Apr 2021
Acquired 685,000
DATO' YEO BOON LEONG
====
16 Apr 2021
Acquired 1,080,000
DATO' YEO BOON LEONG
====
16 Apr 2021
Acquired 685,000
DATO' YEO BOON LEONG
====
14 Apr 2021
Acquired 50,000
MR LIM TECK SENG
====
```

Comment: For the one that have data at the table, yes I succesfully get the data. But the issue is, if the table is empty, findAll() is throwing error and I couldnt counter it with error handling (if else, except). 0105 has data, but not for 5090.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import httpx
import trio
import pandas as pd

codes = ["5090", "0105"]

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0"
}


async def worker(channel):
    async with channel:
        async for client, code in channel:
            params = {
                "securityCode": code
            }
            r = await client.get('https://www.malaysiastock.biz/Corporate-Infomation.aspx', params=params)

            try:
                df = pd.read_html(
                    r.text, attrs={"id": "ctl19_gvShareholdingChange"})[0]

            except ValueError:
                df = "N/A"

            print("{}\nCode: {}\n{}".format("*" * 70, code, df))


async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=None) as client, trio.open_nursery() as nurse:
        client.headers.update(headers)
        sender, receiver = trio.open_memory_channel(0)

        async with receiver:
            for _ in range(2):
                nurse.start_soon(worker, receiver.clone())

            async with sender:
                for code in codes:
                    await sender.send([client, code])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    trio.run(main)
```

Output:

```
**********************************************************************
Code: 0105
  Date of change              Shares Director/Substantial Shareholder
0    23 Jun 2021    Acquired 200,000                 MR LIM TECK SENG
1    22 Jun 2021    Acquired 200,000                 MR LIM TECK SENG
2    23 Apr 2021    Disposed 750,000                 MR LIM TECK SENG
3    19 Apr 2021  Acquired 2,040,000             DATO' YEO BOON LEONG
4    19 Apr 2021  Acquired 2,040,000             DATO' YEO BOON LEONG
5    16 Apr 2021  Acquired 1,080,000             DATO' YEO BOON LEONG
6    16 Apr 2021    Acquired 685,000             DATO' YEO BOON LEONG
7    16 Apr 2021  Acquired 1,080,000             DATO' YEO BOON LEONG
8    16 Apr 2021    Acquired 685,000             DATO' YEO BOON LEONG
9    14 Apr 2021     Acquired 50,000                 MR LIM TECK SENG
**********************************************************************
Code: 5090
N/A
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. Itried your code and it's work! But I need to learn more how to read this code and the purpose of httpx and trio as its really new stuff for me. Thanks a lot for this!

Comment: This is an `Asynchronous` code, Explaining async code requiring a lot. the code which you are using is act like threading but in parallel mode. you could check [httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org/) and [trio](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) documentation. `HTTPX` is 10x faster than requests btw and it's supporting `async`

Comment: Thanks! Will look into for faster way!